# Usage of the DISTINCT keyword through haskell persist

Tags: haskell, persistent

Is there some way in Haskell persistent to perform a `select distinct (column_name_1, column_name_2) ...`. Note that I do not mean unique, I really want to select the distinct records for these columns. I can of course perform some filter-magic afterwards, but I would like to have the database (in my case postgres) solve it, but I did not really find this in the documentation.

Kasper

Answer (score 1):

A search of the [`persistent` repo](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent) shows that the `DISTINCT` keyword is not used in any meaningful context, meaning that `persistent` does not support `DISTINCT` queries at all.

The reason for this is because an explicit design goal of persistent is to be [backend-agnostic](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent#backend-agnostic), and many non-SQL backends do not natively support certain SQL features, such as distinct queries and joins.

I opened a [Github issue](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/issues/1246) to query this, and Matt Parsons, a persistent maintainer, responded recommending the [Esqueleto](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto) package, which is written on top of persistent and aims to provide SQL-specific functionality.